# Missing steps in this simplification of geometric series with logs question?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, logarithms

$$3^{\log_4^n} + \sum_{a=0}^{(\log_4^n)-1}3^a$$

**Attempt**: using formula $\sum_{k=0}^{n}r^k = \frac{{1-r^{n+1}}}{1-r}$ when $ r > 1$, I get:  $$3^{\log_4^n} + \frac{{1-3^{(\log_4^n-1)+1}}}{1-3}
= 3^{\log_4^n} + \frac{{1-3^{\log_4^n}}}{-2}$$

Supposedly, this should end up becoming:

$\frac{3^{\log_4^{4n}}-1}{2}$

But I'm stuck. Somehow $\frac{1-3^{\log_4^n}}{-2}$ is multiplied by $-1$ and $3^{\log_4^n}$ is eliminated completely?

Comment: A common denominator, then a log rule should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last term is $3^{\log_4^n}+\frac{1-3^{\log_4^n}}{-2}$. Computing common denominator gives
$$\frac{-2\times 3^{\log_4^n}+1-3^{\log_4^n}}{-2}=\frac{-3\times 3^{\log_4^n}+1}{-2}=\frac{- 3^{1+\log_4^n}+1}{-2}=\frac{- 3^{\log^4_4+\log_4^n}+1}{-2}$$
Using properties of $\log$ we have
$$\frac{- 3^{\log_4^{4n}}+1}{-2}=\frac{3^{\log_4^{4n}}-1}{2}$$

Comment: What log property would that be? -log_b(a) = log_b(1/a)?

Comment: $\log^A_a+\log^B_a=\log^{AB}_a$